# Create symbolic link in Windows 7 for Google Chrome storage

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, symbolic-link

Google Chrome, and for that matter all Google apps are eating up my hard drive space.
I want to tell Chrome to use some other directory for storing all the data.

I followed the technique of adding parameters to Shortcut `--user-dir=my\new\dir\name`, but it works only when opening Chrome with that shortcut.

So when I double click an **`.html`** file, Chrome ignores the parameter. (I am a Web Developer)

I tried telling my OS to treat new directory and fool Google using hard symlinking.

But this didn't work

```
mklink /J C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\Google F:\Google
```

Says: cannot create a directory when one already exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Solution

1. Make sure all Google programs are closed.
2. Rename the `Google` folder in `C:\Users\<Name>\AppData\Local` to `Google.old` (or whatever, as long as it's different).
3. Migrate all files from the old folder to the new one (e.g. `F:\Google`).
4. Create the junction point:

   ```
   mklink /j "C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\Google" "F:\Google"
   ```

Comment: ... and then migrate all original files from old folder to new F:\Google. Yup that's what I did. It worked. Awesome. 
Accepting your answer as it solves my mentioned question.

Comment: I've been junctioning Google's 1'000's of files to another drive like this for years.  This works like a charm.  Don't forget to write it down so you can do it again down the road!

Comment: @OmShankar Yeah, I assumed you moved the files already. Also, you should be enclose paths in double quotes to avoid issues with space characters. Editing my answer.